# Gradle error msg "Could not find property on project" when exporting a property

Tags: java, gradle, war

I have a multi-project that looks like this:

```
main-web-app
\- web-app-1
\- web-app-2
```

Each module has it's **build.gradle** file. I need to generate a **main-web-app.war** (actually, a directory with the war exploded) that is going to include all the contents from the sub-modules.

So each of the sub-modules build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
//...
task explodedWar(type: Copy) {
    project.ext.buildExplodedDir = "$buildDir/webapps/web-app-1"
    into "$buildDir/webapps/web-app-1"
    with war
}
war.dependsOn explodedWar
```

and the main-web-app **build.gradle** (and here's the problem) should look something like this:

```
war {
    from fileTree(project(':web-app-1').buildExplodedDir)
    from fileTree(project(':web-app-2').buildExplodedDir)
}
```

But then I get this error message:

```
Could not find property 'buildExplodedDir' on project ':web-app-1'
```

What would be the correct way of making my parent project find what's the "buildExplodedDir"?

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'war'
//...
task explodedWar(type: Copy) {
    if (!rootProject.hasProperty('buildExplodedDir')) {
        rootProject.ext.buildExplodedDir = []
    }
    rootProject.ext.buildExplodedDir << "$buildDir/webapps/web-app-1"

    into "$buildDir/webapps/web-app-1"
    with war
}
war.dependsOn explodedWar
```

You might also need to tell gradle to parse the submodules first.  So in your parent gradle file just add something like this

`project.evaluationDependsOnChildren()`